# How to find if any method is being used/inherited in other class files using c# code and not through FIND ALL REFERENCE?

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance

I have a method in a class file. Say,

```
class A
{
     public void Getmethod(int first,int second)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("GetMethod");
        }
}
```

In my another class file, I have the following code

```
class B: A
    {
        A obj = new A();
        public  void  callingfunction()
         {
            obj.Getmethod(2,3);
         }
    }
```

Suppose I am storing the `"Getmethod"` name in a string variable, say `Methodname`. Is it posiible to find if my `Methodname` is being used anywhere else in my solution(that is it should check in all class files of a solution)

Comment: @Peter Duniho I am finding for C# CODE for this question and not through FIND ALL REFERENCE. So it is not a Duplicate

Comment: Actually it *is* a duplicate as the answer to the duplicate question tells you what you need to do.

Comment: Did you bother to look at the marked duplicate? It is _exactly_ the question you asked, and _not_ about using "Find All References..." in the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the method in Visual Studio and Click `Find All References`

[Finding References](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/VSFindAllReferences.aspx)

Comment: I am finding a C# programming code to find this. And not through `Find All Reference`

Comment: The only way to do that will be to actually run the code through a compiler and then analyze the results while it is still in a syntax tree or similar. Due to the optimizing nature of compilers the code may be optimized out before it reaches the final stage so looking at assemblies on disk may or may not give you what you want. May I ask *why* you need to do this yourself?